# URL location can someone explain?

Tags: javascript

I am just starting to learn location API(s), such as redirection URL in javascript and I can not understand the following three lines,
Can someone explain me?

```
let windowUrl = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
const queryString = window.location.href;
const firstParam = queryString.substring(queryString.lastIndexOf("?") + 1).split("=")[0];
```

Comment: This code makes no sense. It uses `window.location.search` and creates a `URLSearchParams` object which is great. The completely ignores it and uses `window.location.href` to get `queryString.substring(queryString.lastIndexOf("?") + 1)` which is essentially `window.location.search`. `URLSearchParams` does keep the query parameter order so `firstParam` could be `windowUrl.keys()?.[0]`

Comment: @apokryfos Please post as answer so we can vote it up

Answer (score 3):

The first line is useless. As you can see, windowUrl never gets used.

The following two lines:

window.location.href is nothing but the URL that you see in your browser's location bar. Say, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=123456

so `queryString = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=123456"`

what the 2nd line does is to take everything that comes after "?" in that string. So `v=123456`

Then, it splits `v=123456`  by "=" as a separator. So, finally you get `123456`.

Now, all of the above is quite barbaric, as you could obtain the value that "v" parameter this way:

```
let url = new URL(window.location.href);
let v   = url.searchParams.get("v");
```

URL is an interface that will, shall we say "analyze" a URL and give you methods to parse it conveniently, such as the searchParams method, and more.

MDN https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL

Answer (score 0):

`let windowUrl = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search)` ==> fetching URL params from the url. E.g website.com/?**hello=1**

`const queryString = window.location.href;` ===> getting the URL of your current page.

`const firstParam = queryString.substring(queryString.lastIndexOf("?") + 1).split("=")[0];`  ===> String manipulation to get the first param from the URL. Would open dev tool and play with it, to get the feeling.

E.g:

```
const x = "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69835761/js-url-location-can-someone-explain/?hello=1"
const x = "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69835761/js-url-location-can-someone-explain/?hello=1"
console.log(x)
```

Result: 'hello'

Answer (score 0):

Description inline the code:

```
// for Example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69835761/js-url-location-can-someone-explain?search=hello

windowUrl = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
// URLSearchParams object that helps you to provide data to the query url
// window.location.search will return the current search query from your url

queryString = window.location.href;
// the current url: in this case: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69835761/js-url-location-can-someone-explain?search=hello

firstParam = queryString.substring(queryString.lastIndexOf("?") + 1).split("=")[0]
// you filter or prase the value from the query string
```

But you can have it easier, like @resle already wrote.

```
// get the current url
const uri = new URL(window.location.href);
const quersValue = uri.searchParams.get("search");
// output : hello
```

Answer (score 0):

So here's a breakdown of what the code does:

```
let windowUrl = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
```

Here an instance of a [URLSearchParams](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParamse) object which parses the `search` (effectively the query string).

```
const queryString = window.location.href;
```

This grabs the `href` (i.e. the entire URL including the query string and hash) and names it `queryString` (very bad name)

```
const firstParam = queryString.substring(queryString.lastIndexOf("?") + 1).split("=")[0];
```

This grabs the variable named "queryString" which is the `href` and finds the last index of `?` which the code author hoped would designate the place where the query string starts (which is not correct). It then does some string manipulation to attempt get the first query string parameter key which would probably work for most cases but not all.

This code can be greatly simplified to:

```
const firstParam = (new URL(window.location.href)).searchParams.keys()?.[0];
```

This will use the JS [URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/URL) class to parse the URL correctly and get the first key of the search parameters. `?.[0]` is the [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) operator for arrays

Note that the 3rd line is wrong in this case because a URL like `https://example.com/test?param=a&other=b&param=c#hashwith?questionmark`
is valid but the code will think the first URL parameter is `questionmark` instead of `param` which would be the expected answer.